# npm install angular material data table

Tags: npm, angular-material, npm-install

I am on win 10.trying to install **angular-material-data-table** on my working folder.npm install angular-material-data-table --save.its gives me the following error...,

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mission>npm install angular-material-data-table --save
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'C:\xampp\htdocs\mission\package.json' C:\xampp\htdocs\mission
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@^1.4.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-material@^1.0.0 `-- angular-material-data-table@0.10.10

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'C:\xampp\htdocs\mission\package.json' npm WARN
angular-material-data-table@0.10.10 requires a peer of angular@^1.4.0
but none was installed. npm WARN angular-material-data-table@0.10.10
requires a peer of angular-material@^1.0.0 but none was installed. npm
WARN mission No description npm WARN mission No repository field. npm
WARN mission No README data npm WARN mission No license field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to learn how to use npm:

1. Create an `project.json` file via `npm init`
2. Than add all required libraries:

   `npm install angular@1.4.7 --save`
   `npm install angular-material@1.0.0 --save`
3. After that you can install the module you need

   `npm install angular-material-data-table --save`